# Use 2 column for training data in machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe named `ds` with 3 column of data as follows

```
         text     count      label
0   I have...        12        pos   
1   You sh...         8        neg
2   In thi...         9        neg
.
.
```

I was given an example by using only `text` for creating test and training data with code like

```
X = ds['text']
y = ds['label']
train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=0)

df_train75 = pd.DataFrame()
df_train75['text'] = train_X
df_train75['label'] = train_Y

df_test25 = pd.DataFrame()
df_test25['text'] = test_X
df_test25['label'] = test_Y

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

tfidf_vect_7525 = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range = (1, 1))
tfidf_vect_7525.fit(ds['text'])
train_X_tfidf_7525 = tfidf_vect_7525.transform(df_train75['text'])
test_X_tfidf_7525 = tfidf_vect_7525.transform(df_test25['text'])

from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(train_X_tfidf_7525,train_Y)
```

==================================================================================

I tried to include `text` and `count` column by simply changing the first line with

```
X = ds[['text', 'count']
```

And it gives me error on

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC

model = SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(train_X_tfidf_9010,train_Y)
```

==================================================================================

My question is, how should I approach this problem? I tried to look into other question but failed to have an answer. One "solution" I found is by using

```
X = ds['text'].astype(str) + ' ' + ds['count'].astype(str)
```

but I don't think it was the correct option to approach this problem.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you want to transform different columns of the input separately, you should choose [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html). You can also choose to not transform specific columns. In any case, the results of each (non-)transformation will be concatenated again into a single array. A small example:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'text': ['This is doc1', 'This is doc2', 'Here is doc3']*3,
    'count': [12, 8, 9]*3,
    'label': ['pos', 'neg', 'neg']*3
})

X = df[['text', 'count']]
y = df['label']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)

transformer = ColumnTransformer([
    ('vectorizer', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1)), 'text')
], remainder='passthrough')

X_vec_train = transformer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_vec_test = transformer.transform(X_test)

model = SVC(kernel='linear')
model.fit(X_vec_train, y_train)
```

The syntax for the list of transformers is a list of tuples with `(name, transformer, columns)`, where you can specify which transformer to apply to which column. By setting `remainder='passthrough'`, all remaining columns that were not specified previously will be automatically passed through and will just be concatenated with the result. For more on this, see the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).